# DP-Coin Change result getting zero

Tags: java, algorithm, dynamic-programming, coin-change

So this is my code where I'm trying to find out the minimum number of coins to make up my target amount from unlimited supply of coins. My problem is instead of getting the required coin number, I'm getting 0. So how can I fix it. And sorry if i'm not clear. My english isn't that good :( . Here is my code:

```
import java.util.*;
public class CoinChangeDP{
   public static int[] c = {1,2,2,5,5,5,10};
   public static int amount = 15;
   public static int[][] dp = new int[c.length+1][amount+1];
   public static void main(String[] args){
      System.out.println("Minimum number of coin required: "+CoinChange(0, amount));
  }
  public static int CoinChange(int index, int amount){
     int n = c.length;
     if(index>=n){
        if(amount==0)
           return 0;
        else
           return Integer.MAX_VALUE;
     }
     if(dp[index][amount]!=-1){
         return dp[index][amount];
     }
     int ret1, ret2;
     if(amount>=c[index]){
         ret1 = 1+CoinChange(index, amount-c[index]);
     }else{
         ret1 = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
     }
     ret2 = CoinChange(index, amount);
     dp[index][amount] = Math.min(ret1, ret2);
     return dp[index][amount];
 }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

`dp` array is initialized with zeros, so when your first call checks:

```
if(dp[index][amount]!=-1){
         return dp[index][amount];
}
```

it will return `0`. Fill your `dp` array with `-1` before calling `coinChange()` function:

```
for (int[] d : dp) {
    Arrays.fill(d, -1);
}
System.out.println("Minimum number of coin required: "+CoinChange(0, amount));
```

**EDIT:**
Here is a fixed version of your function (follow the comments):

```
 public static int CoinChange(int index, int amount){
     int n = c.length;
     // check if at any point we reached 0 amount (got a solution)
     if (amount == 0) {
         return 0;
     }
     // if we reached the end of the array and we still have amount > 0
     if (index == n){
         return Integer.MAX_VALUE;
     }
     // if we already processed the value for this index/amount
     if (dp[index][amount] != -1){
         return dp[index][amount];
     }
     int ret1, ret2;
     if(amount >= c[index]){
         // take this coin and stay on same index
         ret1 = 1+CoinChange(index, amount-c[index]);
     }else{
         ret1 = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
     }
     // do not take this coin and go to next index
     ret2 = CoinChange(index+1, amount);
     dp[index][amount] = Math.min(ret1, ret2);
     return dp[index][amount];
 }
```

And about your question about unlimited supply, here the states are either take the coin and stay on the same index (take or leave on next call), or leave it and go to next index. The first function call will try taking or leaving the coin as long as it is <= the amount, so this will cover all the possible scenarios.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but it actually showing StackOverflowError in ret2 = CoinChange(index, amount) line :(

Comment: Because it will keep running forever, that line needs to be changed to `ret2 = CoinChange(index+1, amount);` which means you don't take the current coin and move to the next coin

Comment: but i've infinite number of supply. so don't you think it should stays there until it covers up the amount?

Comment: and also it is now giving negative max integer value

Comment: Let me rewrite my answer to fix all the issues in your code with explanation